# Deriving the asymptotic distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics, normal-distribution, variance

Let $x_1, ..., x_n$ and $y_1, ..., y_n$ be two independent random samples from $X$ and $Y$. 
We have $µ_X = E (X ) > 0, µ_Y = E (Y ) > 0$ and $σ^2_X = Var (X )$ and $σ^2_Y = Var (Y )$.
Derive the asymptotic distribution of $\frac{\overline x_n+ \overline y_n}{\overline x_n- \overline y_n}$.

Could you guys help out.

Really looked at the other peoples questions and I am clearly over my head with this. Really need the help, wished I could put more of my steps down but just hitting a wall. I saw that many people have questions related to this so I think that could help many.

Comment: Use the "delta method".

Comment: Thanks kmchi lover for the interest. What is the delta method, would you mind expanding on it? How would I go about it. Really need the help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method

Comment: I looked at it, but I don't understand how I can apply it. I know it must be inconvenient for you but would you mind showing me the step by step. I really want to understand it

Comment: Let me ask, is your $\frac{x_n+y_n}{x_n-y_n}$ correct?  Should it be something like $\frac{\bar x_n+\bar y_n}{\bar x_n-\bar y_n}$, instead, where $\bar x_n$ is the sample average of the $x_i$ and so on?

Comment: Oh yes I think that is the correct way. The book is kind of old I just assumed the lines were dirt. Would you know how to do it with the \bar x_n

Comment: Edit your question accordingly, please.  I will try to compose a delta-method answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wished you could see how appreciative I am right now. BIG Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by a straight forward application of the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).  To simplify notations I will use the shorthand  $f(x,y)$ for the ratio $(x+y)/(x-y)$, and for the partial derivatives $f_x = \partial f/\partial x$ and $f_y=\partial f/\partial y$.  Also  $a$ and $b$ are shorthands for $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$.

What follows assumes that $a\ne b$ and that $\tau^2=f_x(a,b)^2\sigma_X^2+f_y(a,b)^2\sigma^2_Y>0$.  Otherwise things become more complicated,
as indicated in whuber's comment.

The OP wants to know the asymptotic distribution of $f(\bar x_n, \bar y_n)$, where $\bar x_n$ is the sample average of the $x$s and $\bar y_n$ of the $y$s.  By the central limit theorem, which applies because $\sigma^2_X$ and $\sigma^2_Y$ are both finite, $z_n:=\sqrt n (\bar x_n-a)$ tends in distribution to a $N(0,\sigma_X^2)$ random variable and $w_n:=\sqrt n (\bar y_n-b)$ tends in distribution to a $N(0,\sigma_Y^2)$ random variable. So write $(\bar x_n,\bar y_n) =(a,b)+(z_n,w_n)/\sqrt n$ and expand $f(\bar x_n,\bar y_n)$ is a Taylor series, truncating with the linear term, so $$
f(\bar x_n,\bar y_n) =f(a,b)+f_x(a,b) \frac{z_n}{\sqrt{n}} + f_y(a,b) \frac{w_n}{\sqrt{n}} + \cdots$$
and $$
\sqrt n\left(f(\bar x_n,\bar y_n)-f(a,b)\right) = f_x(a,b){z_n} +f_y(a,b) {w_n}+\cdots.\tag{*}$$
As explained in the cited reference, the $+\cdots$ terms do not affect the answer.  Since $z_n$ and $w_n$ are converging in distribution to a gaussian limit, the right hand side in (*) is too, to $N(0,\tau^2)$, where $\tau^2=f_x^2 \sigma_X^2 + f_y^2\sigma_Y^2.$

The idea here is that after recentering and  rescaling, your random variable is approximately a fixed linear combination of $\bar x_n$ and $\bar y_n$, with coefficients $f_x(a,b)$ and $f_y(a,b)$, and so has variance $f_x(a,b)^2\text{Var}(\bar x_n) + f_y(a,b)^2\text{Var}(\bar y_n)=\tau^2/n$.

Comment: Wow, so the asymptotic distribution would be $N(0,$t^2$)$ because of $z_n$ and $w_n$ converging to the gaussian limit. You just assumed because of the strictly positive expected values of both $X$ and $Y$. Is that how I am to understand the process? Super interesting this delta method. Had never heard of it before. So appreciative of your support

Comment: Is the square root going over n and (xn-a) or only over n?

Comment: Just over $n$.  Root of $n$ times the difference of $(\bar x_n-a)$ . I just fixed a typo: I had written $x_n$ but should have $\bar x_n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. It will take me a bit to understand where tau comes from but this at least shows me that there is a way to get to the asymptotic distribution

Comment: Are you sure it’s not (\mu) rather than f

Comment: In which equation, in which sentence?

Comment: The result, I just can’t replicate the asymptotic distribution meaning tau seems to escape me. Could it be that there is a step there that is missing or that I am just to slow to get it

Comment: Meaning \mu squared of x and \mu squared of y rather than the f’s

Comment: Clearly this approach is problematic when $\mu_X\approx \mu_Y:$ one would expect convergence to a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: @whuber Yes; it was careless writing on my part to leave this out.  I have rewritten my answer to sort-of answer this case.

Comment: @James  I stand by my $\tau^2$ stuff, and have added in a bit more explanation.  Of course $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ show up in the formula for $f_x(a,b)$, etc, so maybe you are reacting to a familiar quantity showing up in an unfamiliar algebraic re-expression.